# Join methods to run at the same time - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I am new to node js, and have a method in my code which saves information in the following way:

```
var saveInformation = function(query, update, options) {
  asyncTasks.push(function(done) {
    what.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, done)
  })
}

saveInformation(query, update, options)
```

I call the `saveInformation` method on several occasions, and need to write to the log files every time this method is called. What is the easiest way of doing this?

I tried just adding my log (I am using winston module) right after, like this:

```
saveInformation(query, update, options)
logger.info('Hello')
```

However this sometimes saves and sometimes not (i.e. it will only log this once, however this method is run several times throughout my program).

So I am wondering, is there a way to add another method to the saveInformation line to ensure that they are both run at the same time, so when `saveInformation` is saved to the dbs, I get a log created too?

Answer (score 0):

The call to the logging function should be in the callback of the function `what.findeOneAndUpdate` which is `done` in this case, this way it will execute after each operation.

```
// callback for findOneAndUpdate
var done = function(err, result) {
    if(err) {
        throw err
    }
    logger.info('Result of findOneAndUpdate: ', result)
}
//

// original code
var saveInformation = function(query, update, options) {
    asyncTasks.push(function(done) {
        what.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, done)
    })
}

saveInformation(query, update, options)
```

This way whenever `saveInformation` is called the logger will be called if the callback is called with no error, you can also modify that to log errors as well if you like.

Comment: I see what you do there, however in my case every logger.info has a different content, so I guess I cant have different done variables for every logger. As there will be loads of them. Any other solution?

Comment: @deeveeABC If you want the logging statement to be printed after the findAndUpdate operation has occurred, it has to be in its callback. Therefore you would have to think of a way to send the message that is to be logged to the callback function.

You can also do a logging statement before the call, stating that the operation of saving X is being started, and another one in the callback saying that operation Y has been completed successfully or with an error. It can contain data from the model being saved so that you can differentiate messages for example.